# Knock out list binding with unordered list

Tags: jquery, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm really new to knock out, I'm having the issue with list bindings.

```
   var RequiredItemLine = function () {

            var self = this;
            self.editable = ko.observable(0);
            self.desc = ko.observable();
            self.key = ko.observable();

            self.requireditems = ko.observableArray([
                  { desc: "Boarding of exposed wall openings in the vicinity of ...", key: "233" },
                  { desc: "Call in manufacturers to initiate repairs on ...", key: "242" },
                  { desc: "Call in specialist restorers/recoverers for ...", key: "244" },
                  { desc: "Dispatch items for repair (schedule enclosed)", key: "243" },
                  { desc: "Drying and cleaning of contents comprising ...", key: "240" },
                  { desc: "Drying and protective oiling of water affected equipment", key: "241" },
                  { desc: "Drying out of the affected areas of the premises", key: "235" },
                  { desc: "Removal and repackaging of stock comprising ...", key: "239" },
                  { desc: "Removal of agreed vulnerable contents to a place of safety (schedule enclosed) ", key: "236" },
                  { desc: "Segregation of affected and unaffected stock comprising ...", key: "238" },
                  { desc: "Temporary covering of roof to reinstate water tight integrity ", key: "234" },
                  { desc: "Temporary guarding of affected area", key: "237" },
                  { desc: "Temporary shoring of affected structure", key: "232" }]);

            self.selectedItem = ko.observable(self.requireditems()[0]);



            self.selectedItem.subscribe(function (newValue) {

                var li = "<li>" + newValue.desc + "</li>";

                $('#items').append(li);


            });       
        };


        var RequiredItem = function () {

            var self = this;

            self.requireditemSelection = ko.observableArray([]); // Put one line in by default


            self.requireditemlines = ko.observableArray([]);

            // Operations
            self.addRequiredItem = function () { self.requireditemSelection.push(new RequiredItemLine()) };
            self.RemoveRequiredItem = function (line) { self.requireditemSelection.remove(line) };


        };


        ko.applyBindings(new RequiredItem());
```

please look on this fiddle.  [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/2fF5g/),In the page contains a button to add select list, when ever a button is clicked a new select list will be added to DOM. when the user select the item from one of the select list the selected item should be displayed separately and when ever the user change the selected item which already displayed in the DOM  has to changed according to the selection, rather than appending a new li.

[image]

please see the second image, I don't want to show another list item, instead of I would like to change the currently added item.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're very close. I'm not 100% sure if I've understood your question correctly, I've interpreted your issue as "wanting to display all selected items in a read-only list".

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fF5g/1/), where I've merely changed the `ul` to this:

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: requireditemSelection'>
    <li data-bind="text: selectedItem().desc"></li>
</ul>
```

You don't need to manually create `li` items and add them to the DOM. Just let KO handle that for you, and data-bind read-only items as well.

Comment: Yes.thank you @jeroen that is the way i want. but is there is any way to stop selected item showed in the unrecorded list while clicking the add button. when the user select the item from the list only the selected item has to be shown inside ul.

Comment: You want an `<ul>` *list* with only one item? What do you mean then by "selected"? If there are multiple `<select>`s there are also multiple selected items? Or do you mean you want to track which `<select>` has [*focus*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection)?

Comment: Yes select has focus only the selected item has to be shown in the ul. at the moment when i click add button at the same time ul also updated, but i want if the select is changed, only the selected value has to be shown in the ul.

Comment: You could have a look at the [`hasFocus`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) binding, though it's not trivial for `select` lists I believe. If you run into specific problems with it be sure to ask a follow-up question on SO.